# How to choose the most appropriate measure of genetic distance

Tags: population-genetics, phylogenetics, molecular-evolution

I am conducting a phylogeography study of a fish species and am trying to construct a phylogenetic tree to describe population structure and ancestry. I have constructed trees using various measures of genetic distance, such as Nei's DA, DS, and Edwards Chord distance. The answers I get between these measures are conflicting, but each explained by a sound hypothesis, and so I must carefully and objectively choose which measure of genetic distance is to be most trusted given my data.
So my question to the community is not, "which should I choose?" but "how should I choose?" I am interested in an answer or (ideally) resource that describes what factors I should take into account and that may bias my result.

Comment: Just curious, but is there a reason why you didn't mention/aren't concerned with Centimorgans? I only ask because I'm uneducated in phylogenetics, but when I was studying genetics (in university), that was the unit we used to measure relative chromosomal "distances".

Comment: I think we are at cross purposes: cenimorgans describe the statistical distance (linkage) of markers from one another on one genome. What I am interested in is the distance in terms of divergence between multiple genomes (population samples) for the same marker or set of markers.

Comment: Yes,  I remember we were studying linkage analysis at the time of that unit being introduced. Makes complete sense!

Comment: Have you looked at [Rogers, Deriving Phylogenetic Trees from Allele Frequencies: A Comparison of Nine Genetic Distances](https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article-abstract/35/3/297/1669406)?